# Sudden black screen while extracting rar (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, thinkpad, compression

I was in the middle of extracting a rar file when my screen blacked out (it looked like my screen when the power is off). I forced restart by pressing long on the power button of my laptop but it didn't restart. The icon notifications show that the laptop is on and it is connected to the adapter.

Is there anyway I can fix this without going to the service center?

I'm using a ThinkPad R61i Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit 3.8gb RAM 160gb hard drive.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a dead screen. It probably has nothing to do with what you were doing. If you have a spare monitor, try hooking your laptop up to that to be sure, but you will probably need to replace the screen. Also, if your laptop has any kind of brightness setting, I'd try and make sure it didn't just get set real low for some reason.

Comment: May I know what could be the reasons for a dead screen? I've always handled my laptop with care. I'll see what I can do with connecting it to a spare monitor. I'm 100% it's not the brightness setting though because the screen is totally black like when laptop is turned off.

Comment: There's a million reasons the screen could die.  Faulty connector at the motherboard, broken wires internally, etc.  I had this issue with my own monitor, once, Dell replaced it for free (granted I had the total care plan).

Comment: It's not always user error. :-) Like anything else, sometimes there are manufacturing defects, and stuff just gets old and breaks. My guess is if you look very very close, you may be able to see the image. When you can see it up close like that, that means that it is the LCD backlight, which may or may not help you.

Comment: I hooked my ThinkPad to another laptop and it looks like the problem is with my ThinkPad's screen because when screen-switched, the spare laptop's screen turns black too. :(